# web2py: interface for "admin" users to create new users?

Tags: web2py

I want to disable normal registering in my web2py app and only allow certain "admin" users to create new users. I know how to disable registering, but I don't know how to make an interface for users to create other users. What I want is a page similar to `[app]/default/user/register` or `[app]/appadmin/insert/db/auth_user` but accessible while you are logged in and only to "admin" users. I could make a simple HTML form, but then I would lose all the important validators and such the normal registering has, and more importantly, I would needlessly repeat someone else's work and not do it the "web2py" way.

(To more elaborate, my groups have certain "group_master" users, saved in "group_master" table in database. And I want only group_masters to access the create_user page, and after the user is created, it will automatically join the group_master's group. I think I know how to deal with the group membership hassle in code, but I need help to create the interface.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the user input, you can either create a custom form or use something like `SQLFORM(db.auth_user).process(dbio=False)` (the `dbio=False` prevents the automatic creation of a database record upon submission of the form). You can then register the user via:

```
auth.register_bare(email=request.vars.email, password=request.vars.password)
```

Comment: Something like this?

    `def create_user():
this_form = SQLFORM(db.auth_user).process(dbio=False)
if this_form.accepts(request.vars, dbio=False):
auth.register_bare(email=request.vars.email, password=request.vars.password)
#Do something
return dict(this_form=this_form)`

Comment: Sure, though you would not call both `.process()` and `.accepts()` on the same form object (the former actually calls the latter). If you have already called `.process()` on a form, then you can just do `if form.accepted:` to test if has passed validation.

Comment: This seems to work, and I added a few arguments to add first_name and last_name as well. But it also adds email as registration_id for the user. I don't know what is the purpose of registration_id anyway, so it doesn't seem to matter (I can log in normally etc with the new users). Does it matter?

Comment: No, doesn't matter.